# How to change a text color inside a shape in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

How do I change the color of the text inside a label shape? I dont want to change the color of the label so that it maintains a contrast.

plotshape(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, color=lime, style=shape.labelup, text='BUY')
plotshape(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, color=red, style=shape.labeldown, text='SELL')

Answer (score 1):

`plotshape()` function has `color` and `textcolor` arguments.

***color*:** Color of the shape.

***textcolor*:** Color of the text.

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)
plotshape(series=close > open, text="Green\nCandle", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, textcolor=red, size=size.small)
```

[image]